# R shiny keep dropping offline while running long process

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing to seek help on the issues in R shiny in relation to the long running process. My codes involved running several simulations which takes about 1 min to run in R console. However, when i run it in the Shiny app, the app just keeps dropping offline at about 20 seconds of running. Does anybody know the reason for this problem and how to fix it?

It would be really helpful to get some insights and potential solutions on this. Thank you.

**--- Further edit below: hope the information below would be useful to clarify the problem.**

The error message is not a real error message: the app just simply drops offline and asks to reload the page. Here is the app that we developed:https://glasgowhehta.shinyapps.io/MetaInsight_continuous_Bayesian/

(Apologies, due to the nature of the issue we could not think how to give a simple example.)

If you click the ‘Data analysis’ tab - ‘3. Bayesian network meta-analysis’ tab - ‘3d. Nodesplit model’ tab, then click the button ‘Click here to run the main analysis for all studies’, it will drop the app offline before generating results (but this will take nowhere near as long as it would take for the server to disconnect due to user inactivity). The programme behind this button is a series of simulation evaluations using JAGS (which uses Gibbs Sampling and is computationally intensive and can produce a lot of data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_another_Gibbs_sampler).

When only a small number of simulations are required, results could be rendered, however, when a larger number of simulations are required, the app will drop offline. You could test this by ticking some studies out from the sidebar, say ticking all the studies from ‘Kuo 2006’ down until ‘Derosa 2005’, which will result in only a small proportion of the data entering the ‘nodesplitting analysis with studies excluded’. After ticking these studies out, click the button on the right hand side, ‘Click here to run the nodesplitting analysis with studies excluded’, then the results should be rendered.

So our questions are:

1)  Why does the app drop offline when the background computations are more extensive (i.e. is it a memory or a time issue or another altogether)?

2) What can be done to get round this problem (we have tinkered with the server settings but without success)?

We would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: You should really use shiny for display purpose only, offload the job to another Rscript if it takes too long. You can do that from within `shiny` also. For your problem please post the error messages along with sample code to reproduce

Comment: Hi Pork, many thanks for your reply. To improve clarity, we just added further details to the post. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is probably to late for you but I am looking at building a similar application , I found this link for using async approaches to run processes in the background https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2018/scaling-shiny-apps-with-async-programming/ , I hope its o some use